# Java Clipboard for cut/copy/paste

Tags: java, swt

I am making use of Java SWT Clipboard for Copy/Paste by copying multiple items belonging to same data type. In this case when I retrieve back the items from clipboard I always get the first matching item placed on the clipboard.
Could some one please share their thoughts/opinion in regards to this ?

For Example:

I have three items say `A`, `B`, `C` of same datatype then when I try to retrieve back I always get item `A`.

1. How could this problem be solved?
2. Is there any other clipboard that can be used for copy/paste?

> clipboard.setContents(new Object[] {data1}, new Transfer[]
>   {TextTransfer.getInstance()}); clipboard.setContents(new Object[]
>   {data2}, new Transfer[] {TextTransfer.getInstance()});

when tried to retrieve :

> String data =
>   (String)clipboard.getContents(TextTransfer.getInstance());

Here we always get the data1 which was placed on the clipboard, How do we get the data2?

Comment: what have you done so far???

Comment: @SSH clipboard.setContents(copyItems[], transfers[]) , here copyitems are multiple A,B,C with their respective transfers but when tried to use clipboard.getContents(transfer) here passing the appropriate transfer type         belonging to either A or B or C, here the contents retrieved is always A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a container object that holds a list of items. Then you can put an instance of that container object in the clipboard and load as many items from it as desired.

Comment: Will this have an impact on the performance/memory since we are creating a duplicate copy of the items through container and also need to maintain logic for retrieving them?
In my opinion, since there are multiple items there can be multiple transfer types registered for each item through registerType method. Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 0):

Please see the javadoc of Clipboard.setContents. Calling setContents will clear the previous contents on the clipboard.

> Javadoc: Place data of the specified type on the system clipboard.  More than one type of data can be placed on the system clipboard at the same time.  Setting the data clears any previous data from the system clipboard, regardless of type.

The javadoc also has an example showing how to set different transfer objects on the clipboard.

```
 Clipboard clipboard = new Clipboard(display);
 String textData = "Hello World";
 String rtfData = "{\\rtf1\\b\\i Hello World}";
 TextTransfer textTransfer = TextTransfer.getInstance();
 RTFTransfer rtfTransfer = RTFTransfer.getInstance();
 Transfer[] transfers = new Transfer[]{textTransfer, rtfTransfer};
 Object[] data = new Object[]{textData, rtfData};
 clipboard.setContents(data, transfers);
 clipboard.dispose();
```

Comment: Agreed more than one type of data can be paced, my question was if two items belonging to the same data type is placed then how do you retrieve each one of them ?