# Copy Eclipse text and paste into VB.NET textbox doesn't work

Tags: vb.net, eclipse, textbox, copy-paste, notepad

I have this issue that when I copy (CTRL-C) some text from Eclipse (the well known IDE), and paste it (CTRL-V) in my VB.NET application in a textbox the VB.NET application is not responding for a while and nothing is pasted.
When I first paste it in Notepad ... then copy (CTRL-C) the text in Notepad ... and then paste it in the VB.NET textbox it works fine.

What is causing this issue ? ... and how can I change my VB.NET application so that it will work.

Comment: On Windows? Copied from where exactly? The system clipboard supports different formats (e.g. plain text, HTML, RTF, ...). It seems your VB.NET application tries a different format than plain text and fails.

Comment: Yes, on Windows. Copied from the Eclipse editor (eclipse.org).

Comment: I don't encounter it when copying something out of a Outlook mail or Word ... only from Eclipse. The Eclipse installation was a default installation.

Comment: Are you pasting into a TextBox or a RichTextBox? Is there any code associated with the control?

Comment: a TextBox ... from Notepad no issues.

Comment: Sorry, I was typing as I was thinking, so I had edited that comment while you were typing. Is there any code associated with the TextBox?

Comment: No events at all on the Textbox ... no code written I mean on any event.

Comment: Have you tried starting a new project, with only a TextBox on it, to see if the problem still exists with that simple setup? If the problem has gone, then I suggest deleting the problematic TextBox and making a new one.

Comment: I don't think the textbox is the problem. I have many textboxes in the application ... and it happens on all of them. It must be something in Eclipse, because as said in the original text, when I copy it first in Notepad, then select and copy out of Notepad, then paste in the textbox : no problems at all

Comment: "Copied from the Eclipse editor (eclipse.org)."? eclipse.org is the website of the Eclipse Foundation which hosts more than 400 projects. Are you talking about the Eclipse IDE which provides different editors? In the Eclipse IDE, when you copy text from a Java editor or a different text editor with syntax highlighting, then the system clipboard will contain not only plain text but also rich text in different formats. When you paste the clipboard somewhere, it's up to the client to choose the format. Copying rich text from Eclipse into a text editor and a word processor both work fine for me.

Comment: @kahoona *I don't think the textbox is the problem.* How long is it going to take you to create a new VB.NET Windows Forms project, add one TextBox to the default form, and press F5, just to prove that it isn't the problem? Go for the easy stuff first ;)

Comment: @AndrewMorton ok, I will try that ... will take me 2 weeks, as I'm going on holiday.

Comment: @howlger It's the Eclipse IDE with different editors; we even made our own editor.
Do you know how I can set/choose the format for pasting into my VB.NET textbox ?

Comment: @kahoona Hey, two weeks is way faster than some people take to reply :) I hope you have an enjoyable time away.

Comment: [Here is an example for Eclipse to copy the String `Hello World` as plain text plus the same String formatted as bold and italic as RTF to the clipboard](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33670458/6505250). It's up to the application where you do the paste to choose the format.

Comment: @kahoona For what it's worth, I created a VB.NET Windows Forms .NET 6.0 program with just a TextBox on the form and built it. I installed Eclipse in ther same W11 VM, loaded some random example C++ project, and copied some of the project's code from Eclipse and pasted it into the running VB.NET program. There was no delay.